# Distance Based Metric For Locally Scaled Difference of Distance Between Moving Points

Tags: algorithm, graph, cluster-analysis, metrics, variance

I am trying to form a metric to model the following scenario.

Given various combinations of triples of points (calls those triples abc) in euclidean space, where all points are moving independently over time. Lets imagine that each triple is connected by edges E(a,b) and E(b,c), but no direct edge from a->c.

I am looking to form an error metric, which penalises any changes in the length of edge(a,b) and edge(b,c) and is locally scaled, but also considers the mean total distance walked from a->c...such that those combinations of triples, whose relative scaled interconnected distances remains minimally unchanged and whose walk from a->c is small has the largest "metric" value.

My initial idea is obviously to calculate the standard deviation of edge lengths (a,b) and (b,c) and the mean (a->b->c). Lets call them SD(EL:ab), SD(EL:bc) and M(EL:abc) respectively.

I presume I can also scale both SD's by their respective means or M(EL:abc), to make them locally scaled.

But what I am really not sure of is how best to combine these 3 parameters to best achieve the metric I am looking for.

Any help much appreciated.